# Moment timezone names mapping with standard time zone names

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I went through moment documentations and time zone names are used like "America/New_York" and such whereas, standard time zone names are like "Eastern Standard Time". How can I map these two names? 
There is this moment.tz.names(); that returns moment names like "America/New_York".

How can I map a standard zone name or abbreviation like MST/MDT with monents language "America/New_York"? or vice versa?

Also, moment.tz.names(); returns names but is there any other method that will return offsets, abbreviations as well like a getAllTimeZones() method?
I had to put the values in an object array and get it from there.
Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be clear.  Are you looking for an English-localized, human readable name of the portion of the time zone that is in standard time (as opposed to daylight time)?  Or are you looking for a Windows time zone identifier, such as used by .NET's `TimeZoneInfo` class?  If the latter, see [moment/moment-timezone#462](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/462).

Comment: Hi Matt, I will have to do this on client side, so can't use TimeZoneInfo. I needed mapping between moment names ("America/New_York") and standard names ("Eastern Standard Time") so I can use moment's capabilities. On the view, I get abbreviations like MST/MDT and if I can map it to moment's names then problem solved.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  The term "standard name" is not a thing.  Do you mean the set of IDs that are used by Windows (some of which look like "Eastern Standard Time", some look very different), or do you mean a string to display to your user?

Comment: On abbreviations, the answer is no - because abbreviations can be ambiguous (CST = China Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, Central Standard Time (US), Central Standard Time (Aus), etc.)

Comment: Please also read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: I am sure aware of that, but I am working with a limited set and have no duplication issues. Besides, I do have the full name available as well (Eastern Standard Time). Is there a way to map it to moment names like "America/New_York". What I need to do is - making decisions based on the match...e.g, using moments capabilities to display appropriate time when daylight savings is in effect etc.

Comment: Thanks Matt, it was helpful. In the moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js file available for download from moment's site, they have list of their names and abbreviation mapping as well.

Comment: Yes, I maintain that one. :)  You can go from time zone + timestamp to abbreviation, just not without timestamp, and not in the opposite direction.